# How to make sure subcharts charts are installed before the actual resources

Tags: kubernetes, operators, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-operator

I am trying to create a helm based operator and for most part, I've got it working. However I need to make sure that the subcharts are installed before the operator is trying to create resources from those subcharts. For e.g I have mongodb community-operator helm chart as a subchart. However, when I deploy the operator i get the below error

failed to install release: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "test-mongodb" namespace: "default" from "": no matches for kind "MongoDBCommunity" in version "mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first.

Looks like its trying to create the mongodb instance before actually installing the operator and crds. How can I force it to first install the subcharts and then try to create mongodb instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the **chart.yaml** you can use the **condition** & **tag**

```
dependencies:
- name: subchart
  version: 0.0.1
  repository: https://chart.github.io/helm-charts
  condition: subchart.enabled
```

so if the chart name as **subchart** is not installed already in cluster it will throw the error.

Official doc : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/dependencies/

if you have multiple sub charts as dependencies you can also go with the **tags**

Comment: This is was the way I was able to get it working, Thank you Harsh